# Sh weird command output - vscode remote ssh

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode with remote explorer extension to develop through ssh on remote machine.
The issue is that everytime I write a command inside vscode terminal I get output like that:

```
root@vm:blablabla/blabla# ls
sh: lastcmd: command not found
sh: settitle: command not found
bin  data  extensions
```

So as you can notice almost everytime when I type a command I get ugly output about lastcmd and settitle.
Is there any possibility to ignore those 2 lines?

Answer (score -1):

You can switch to tmux terminal

Go to the `Configure Terminal` setting on the right side of your terminal, then on
`Terminal>integrated:local echo style`.
Edit setting in json and set the default terminal to tmux.